Flyback without using a controller IC
I am looking to design a power supply using flyback with the following parameters:

Input: 40-60VDC
Output > 120VDC
Power: 100W
A control loop that does not use ICs controller but instead uses opamps, pulse generators, comparators, etc.

I would like to refer to some control loop circuits like that from people who have done the problem.

What is the reason for not using controller ICs?

And anyway, the datasheets for such controller ICs provide a lot of information about how the feedback loop(s) work. How much research have you done?

Why does it need to be a flyback type. Please explain. Do you need input-output galvanic isolation? DCM or CCM operation? Rise time to reach 120 volts from dead? Input power source maximum current to be avoided?

There are many routes to this, so I will list just a few offhand.
The Classics
Study old schematics and design books.  Switching power supplies have been around in some capacity or another since the 1960s, back in the days when discrete transistors were all that we had.  Mind, these also tend to be very simple affairs: little in the way of input/output voltage or current control, temperature limiting, frequency (for EMI or input/output ripple purposes), etc., usually concentrating on one aspect (modestly improving on efficiency of a linear supply; steady V or I regulation; etc.), while keeping transistor count low.  Transformers are a common addition, to provide signal inversion, often for regenerative feedback (e.g. blocking and resonant oscillators).
Classic semiconductor databooks are available on archives such as Bitsavers, archive.org and others.  Fairchild, Texas Instruments, Motorola, GE, RCA, etc. are likely choices; consider the general, discrete or power semiconductor databooks specifically, and anywhere from 60s (50s even) to 80s will find interesting material.
Recent examinations online include Usagi Electric's refurbishment of a PDP power supply, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCoO0YV4Vo4 The design uses a common three-terminal regulator (7805 etc.) in a feedback loop to implement a hysteretic control; similar schemes can be found in manufacturer databooks for these, uA723 and others.
Personal Examples
I've dabbled with a few myself.  Here's a discrete flyback design with low-voltage input and dual output:
 
Source: my website, Seven Transistor Labs, LLC, Discrete_Tube_Supply.png
Peak current mode control is combined with frequency foldback to give nimble performance, free (potentially..!) from the subharmonic instability that pure peak-current-mode control is prone to.  (One catch: the voltage feedback divider should sample both outputs, not just one.  This is irrelevant of course if using a single output.)
Simple variations include common-ground boost, tapped boost, SEPIC or inverting (Ćuk) configurations.  Buck can be arranged via a transformation, or added level shifting circuitry.
I also have a semi-integrated variant, using a 555 timer: 
https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/555%20Boost.pdf 
I don't particularly encourage or recommend it, adjusting values is not necessarily straightforward, etc., but it does implement current mode control with a 555.  More of a "can, but should?" example.
An opamps-and-comparators variant is obvious, of course; the 555 can be implemented with comparators and logic (or use transistors for the R-S FF and drivers), or with a comparator wired for hysteresis (which will change the exact control-pin function a bit).
Another option to look at might be hysteretic control, which is easily implemented with a discrete circuit (it's no accident why many historical examples use this).  I wrote an article on it here: 
Switching Fundamentals: Hysteretic Control | Articles | Seven Transistor Labs, LLC

A breadboarded scale model is evaluated, as well as a full-scale pulsed power supply in the subsequent articles.  Note that, while the articles illustrate a fixed-resistance output characteristic, a voltage regulator will need an external error amp.  This is fine; keeping the inner loop to current alone improves performance, and a full CC/CV controlled design can then be implemented in just a handful of transistors.
Notice my emphasis on current-mode control.  This is motivated by reasons from control theory and design reliability.  Many textbooks describe a buck converter (for example) as filtered PWM, but that's the boring, average case that misses all the nuance of a dynamical system.  In particular, a naive attempt can blow itself up on startup alone, nevermind easily anticipated events like accidentally shorting the output, or step changes in input voltage or load current.  Breaking the loop into two parts (inner current loop, outer voltage loop) allows both to be handled in a predictable and consistent manner, fully describing the operating range of the converter and thus its immunity to accidents like that.
